# Alternative for Java Swings in php

Tags: java, php

Can anyone please help me to write php code using the below java code.

I strucked somewhere and i have so many questions:

how to write java JFrame, BorderLayout, setJMenuBar, setVisible  in php.

```
    // init the frame
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(600, 400);
    // set MenuBar
    this.setJMenuBar(getApplicationMenuBar());
    // set ProgressBar
    this.add(getApplicationProgressBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // set InfoPane
    this.add(getInfoPane(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    // set frame to visible
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  PHP is not particularly suited for GUI projects.

Comment: @WaleedKhan There's always PHP CLI, but, still, GUI isn't what it's for.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to read the step file and want to display the objects of the step file.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is not available in PHP. The PHP language does not contain any default GUI at all.

Comment: hi, i'm trying to write step file reading in php using the existing java code.

Comment: If anyone kow about step file parsing, please help me.

Comment: Do this needful as i strucked in the middle of writing the code because i'm not aware of how to write java swings in php.

Comment: If any other alternatives for step file parsing in php are there means can you please suggest me.